# ag-grid + react app - update column width on click

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm using an ag-grid package inside my app to display the table data. And now I need to change the particular column width inside my table according to the user action. I.e user clicks to a column, and the width of this column expands to certain pixels after the second click, it should be initial.

I've already got the all necessary value from the active column (like id, width, etc.), but can't find the proper method to change column width and don't lose the focus state from active cell.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks for your responses and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `columnApi` from any grid events. `columnApi` exposes a function which you can use for your use-case:
`columnApi.setColumnWidth(colKey, newWidth, finished = true)` You can read more about on official [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score -1):

Using Hooks with useRef

```js
const {useRef} = React;
// Example stateless functional component
const SFC = props => {
  
  const divRef = useRef(null)
  
  const changeWidth = () => {
    if (divRef.current){
      divRef.current.style.height = "100px"
    }
  }
  
  return(<div>
          <div style={{backgroundColor:"#000000", height:"50px"}} ref={divRef}>test</div>
          <button type="button" onClick={changeWidth}>Change me</button>
         </div>)
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <SFC/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script></script>
```

Comment: It's totally unrelated.